# percentComplete for Achievements not returning with decimal values

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

From this thread: [about percentComplete in GKAchievement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131728/about-percentcomplete-in-gkachievement)

I've managed to report achievement progress so far and I have no problems when the progress submitted doesn't include decimal values like do a task 10 times to get this x achievement. Each reportProgress will then be 10%.

However, I'm trying to code an achievement which can only be completed after doing a task 1000 times. So that's 0.1 progress for each task done.

Is there a fix on how to get the decimal values when retrieving percentComplete? I'm not sure if the saved value or the returned value is converted to an int.

What I am trying to do is retrieve the current achievement progress from GameCenter and increment it with 0.1d every time the task is done. If I try to report a progress of 4.1d, I get this in the log:

*Reporting achievement de.company.testapp.achievement1, with **4.100000***

That is a system generated log. So is it correct to assume GameCenter is saving it as double with decimals and only returning the whole number when you request for percentComplete?

Sure I could keep a local counter but I'm trying to avoid score inconsistency when the user switches to another device, or if the local authenticated user changes within the device. It might be a little too much to synch scores or update our server to keep track of every single achievement of every single player.

Anybody has any suggestion on how I should properly handle tracking this kind of achievement?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm developing in Unity so I'm using the GameCenterPlatform but I tried retrieving the percentComplete in objective-c side but it also returns whole number for percentCompleted.

Comment: This is a really annoying problem, facing the same thing now. Is there any solution? Or any response from Unity as to what causes it to return with degraded precision?

Answer (score 0):

I think storing locally is your only option. If you're worried about cross device tracking you could try using cloud storage for the specific information. I think that's your only real option for keeping track of information with higher precision than GameCenter will allow, unless you want to also track the information on your own server secondary to GameCenter.

Comment: Hi Mean, that is what we want, not to keep track of the scores in our servers. So I guess this means Apple just declared percentComplete as double but is treating the value as integer? I'm sure this isn't the first case someone needed to report a score with decimal values. I wasn't sure if this was just a bug or if there is already an existing fix but I've been searching for a fix since yesterday but couldn't find a clear one.

Comment: Did you find any success on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking forward for a bug fix from apple related to this issue, but found this...

> Answer from Apple: "The percentages are reported using doubles but
>   stored as whole number percentages, e.g. 1%, 2%, 3%, ..., 100%. You
>   should probably store the progress locally anyways, since they might
>   be someplace they can't connect to Game Center."
>
> For those with access to Apple dev forums:
>   https://devforums.apple.com/message/522769

**Suggestion:**
 - We can use cloud userdefaults preferences for storing our score values. Here is a useful library for cloud preferences 
 https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Zephyr